# Android getting and sending RadioButton id to other activities

Tags: android, android-activity, radio-button

I am creating simple app where there is a lot of radioButtons, but I am not using text in them only adding Background pictures. So after I finished my work with the design I need to do all mechanics. My problem is that i can find information how to send Text of radioButton, but nothing about possible image sending. I found that it's possible to send ID, but I saw that people uses it as int variable. My radiobuttons id's are like jobRB1,jobRB2, jobRB3,...., some are only words like goodCar, badCar and so on. That most confusing part. So my question is how to read radioButton ID's as Strings and then after sending it to other activity set again as background.

I only doing research so I don't have any code right now more than my xml files to show.

Some code (I hope it will help):

```
private RadioGroup firstRadioGroup;
private RadioGroup secondRadioGroup;
private RadioGroup thirdRadioGroup;
private RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4,rb5;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_jobs_page);
    firstRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.jobrbgroup1);
    secondRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.jobrbgroup2);
    thirdRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.jobrbgroup3);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.jobRB1); rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.jobRB2);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.jobRB3); rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.jobRB4);
    rb5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.jobRB5);

public void resetRadioButtons (View view){
    firstRadioGroup.clearCheck();
    secondRadioGroup.clearCheck();
    thirdRadioGroup.clearCheck();
}

public void openReligionsPage (View view){


    if(rb1.isChecked()){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayReligionsPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(rb2.isChecked()){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayReligionsPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(rb3.isChecked()){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayReligionsPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(rb4.isChecked()){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayReligionsPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(rb5.isChecked()){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayReligionsPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: post some code so we can see what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the buttons public and static then from your other activity access them directly.

```
public static RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4,rb5;
```

Example in your second activity

```
MainActivity.rb1.setBackground("");
```

Comment: Can you explain me more? I want to set image which is set on rb1 in JobActivity on new button on new ReligionActivity. How can I do this? And how to set it depending on selection of RadioButton?

Comment: which Activity is the one you posted above JobActivity or ReligionActivity? So what you want to do is take rb1 from JobActivity and make a copy of it in ReligionActivity? Or do you want to change the background of rb1 from ReligionActivity assuming that rb1 is in JobActivity?

Comment: Do something like this in your ReligionActivity  religionrb1.setBackground(JobActivity.rb1.getBackground());

Comment: in Job activity I let say choose rb1 and after clicking button next i want to activity Religion apear with a button which has background similar to rb1

Comment: tried your sugestion, also added @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN), but it doesn't work. I tested it on 4.1.2 Android and it crashes.